# Code - 3140, Message - There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Item Sales Tax "GST" in the Invoice

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am working on a Sync application for Quickbooks Desktop using QBFC so the problem is with Quickbooks Desktop Enterprise 16 CANADA EDITION.
It is working perfectly for Quickbooks Desktop US editions.

Severity - Error, Code - 3140, Message - There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Item Sales Tax "GST" in the Invoice.

The customer has already a sales tax named "GST" in Quickbooks but I am seeing something which might be the cause of problem i.e. Sales Tax Codes are not "Tax" and "Non". There are some other kinds of Tax codes but I also created Tax and Non in the customer's Quickbooks too but the error still persists.

Any help will be appreciated as it is already creating so much problem in account for the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The customer has already a sales tax named "GST" in Quickbooks

The customer probably should not have this.

> but I am seeing something which might be the cause of problem

You're sending an `ItemSalesTaxRef`, and you shouldn't be.

> Sales Tax Codes are not "Tax" and "Non".

Good! You should NOT see a `TAX` or `NON` tax code for QuickBooks Canada.

> also created Tax and Non in the customer's Quickbooks

You shouldn't have.

TLDR:

- Taxes work differently in CA vs. US
- Don't send `ItemSalesTaxRef` for Canadian companies
- Do send the appropriate tax code for each line item (usually something like `GST` or `G` or `E` depending on what province they are in, and what the taxable status of the item is)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Keith. You are exactly right. Does the Tax Code thingy also vary in QB UK and QB Australia ?

Comment: I'm sure it does. I know AU uses GST VAT (similar to Canada I believe). I'm unsure of what the UK uses. I would suspect that CA UK AU are all similar, while the US is the odd man out.

Comment: Yes I explored it a lot . Seems like these taxes are based on the provinces and necessarily GST is not the only one. There can be HST with a code H.
I think the best way here is to fetch default Tax Code for Taxable items already set in Preferences of Sales Tax and then apply it on each of the invoices.

Comment: Yes, what you set SalesTaxCodeRef to depends on your country, on your particular QuickBooks preferences, on the province you're in, etc.   It's not a static value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith for your help.